# Choosing Open GeoSuite package to install on cloud hosting server?

Tags: installation, boundless-suite

Our company has asked me to implement a system to share cartography on the Internet through Open Source GIS technology with our operators.

We have acquired the CloudServer hosting, and we have installed GeoServer from the Open GeoSuite, and I have created an html where I have my map viewer / application created using a geoexplorer link and another with a link from the Open Layers application .(attached image)

How do I configure the web server to share this html with other clients through the web?

[image]